# Get user name and basic detail without using facebook graph api

Tags: database, facebook-graph-api

I am working on a website, I have one problem ..
I have facebook users id in my database, now I want  to get their names using their ids but without using graph api..
Is there any way to  do so..

Comment: What's wrong with the Graph API?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to do this programaticaly... Short answer is - you can't.
If you want to do it manually you can simply navigate to this url:
 `https://facebook.com/profile.php?id={USERS_ID}`
It will give you the users profile page where you can see their name **IF** their profile is publicly available.
Essentially you should request the users names and store them in your database when the users authenticate your application.

Comment: thanks.. but I want user facebook name, I have id using this id I want an array like we get using graph api...

Comment: then use the graph_api/fql... you cant get this information with out it.